# Write VideoWriter before close

Tags: matlab, video-processing

I'm using the `VideoWriter` object to create a movie in Matlab. However, the movie file doesn't write until the program stops.

Is there any way to force it to write as it's going? Looking online I don't see anything.

I'm currently writing to as an avi but I don't care which format I use.

please specify your findings and search result for what you have already tried

Comment: The only way to "force" a write is if you close the `VideoWriter` object using the `close()` function. There's no other way to save the data. The `close` triggers the writing of information at the end of the file to denote a proper video.

Comment: That's annoying. Can I reopen and append then?

Comment: IIRC, there is no support for frame append.  MATLAB's `VideoReader` and `VideoWriter` are very basic tools for reading and writing video.  I would suggest using something like FFMPEG instead to do that kind of stuff.

Comment: Can I ask why you want to "force it to write as it's going"? The reason for waiting until `close` is called is that the video header content *and length* depend on the all of the content that comes afterwards. It would be more expensive to alter a pre-created header at the end (though some formats, QuickTime for one, support putting the "header" at the end of the file).

Comment: Because I am running my program on a cluster and want to be able to see how it's running.

Comment: @user1543042: Then save your frames as still images and compile the video later (or each time you check on the output). Or do both.